# When trying to load a scdeensaver on a DOS emulator I get unable to change to windows. I also get illegal command win

Tags: windows, command, screen, dos

I have been trying to get DOSBox to run Johnny Castaway on my Windows 10 64 bit OS. I would do it by making Screen Launcher to open D-Box and run some special code. I am new to coding with DOS so I don't understand what the errors mean. The code I added in was:

```
mount c c:/dosbox
C:
cd windows
win runexit C:\windows\scrantic.exe /s
exit
```

I really need help because DOS isn't really my thing but Johnny Castaway is great.

I usually get the responses unable to change to windows and Illegal command win
[see attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VuOR.jpg)

Comment: What don't you understand in `unable to change to <some folder name>`? It usually means, there is no such folder. The next error is likewise clear: `Illegal command: <some command>`. It usually means there is no executable with this name in the current folder (which isn't `C:\Windows` but still `C:\ ` due to the previous error)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: `DOSBOX` usually is just that: a (virtual) box with DOS. Usually, there is no Windows. (I'm not even sure if it is possible to install Windows on a DOSBOX - surely nothing above Win98.) Keep in mind, DOSBOX's `C:` drive is in fact a folder (`C:\dosbox`) on your physical system/host OS.